# Detect resource that hangs while loading with javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a bunch of functions that need to be called on `$(window).on('load' ...)`. Occasionally, the site hangs indefinitely while loading. There are a bunch of embeds and other pieces of media being pulled in from various APIs.

Is it possible to detect what is still pending without attaching an event listener to every resource?

**Edit** for clarification:

@PamBlam's comment below was more tuned in to the problem -- I want to be able to do this with javascript, so it could happen client side while my users are browsing.

Specifically, I'd like to be able to identify pending requests and get any relevant details, and send a note to an error logger (such as sentry) to see what specific resources are problems for users on the live site. Perhaps the only solution would be to create a new `loadResource` function (as suggested in some answers) that compiles these details and, after a long timeout, sends a note to the logger if it still hasn't finished. But, this seems like overkill. Also some of these resources are `<iframe>`s that are included in the HTML, so more work to add that in.

What I was hoping for - and I'm guessing that this doesn't exist, as I assume javascript doesn't have permission to see what's happening on the browser level - was something that could, after a long time out, essentially look at the Network tab of dev tools and send a report of what is still pending.

Comment: Why not look at the application resources in dev tools? You can see what files have been loaded already, also if you look in your console you can see if anything has failed to load.

Comment: Add a `var i = 0;` then add `console.log(++i)` after every resource call by copying and pasting. Then good old Control+Z can come into effect when reverting back.

Comment: Just look at the Network tab. There's probably a request that's in the "(pending)" state.

Comment: you guys expect him to tell every single person that uses his page to look at the console?

Answer (score 0):

One of the best ways to debug JavaScript is Chrome DevTools(while I am a big advocate of Firefox, in this case Chrome is just mind blowing). Use debug breakpoints and network to the best of your capabilities.

Appending the link for referral
https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/

Comment: firebug is available on ff and chome, fyi

Comment: Yes I know, and absolutely loved it while was using underscore, vanillaJS and the likes. However with the advent of Angular and React, DevTools has taken a serious step up.

Answer (score 0):

Count how many resources are loading, and decrement the count when each is finished. When the count is zero all resources are done.

```
var resourcesPending = 0;

// Load some resources
resourcesPending++;
loadAResource(function(){
    resourcesPending--;
    if(!resourcesPending) allResourcesLoaded();
});

resourcesPending++;
loadAResource(function(){
    resourcesPending--;
    if(!resourcesPending) allResourcesLoaded();
});

// etc..
```